# how to crop and save an image in a picturebox in strechmode-c#

Tags: c#, image, winforms, visual-studio, picturebox

I am unable to crop an image in a picturebox in strechmode which i tried for weeks and dint get a solution yet. The problem is my images size is say(1200,750) and the picture size is say(450,300) but when i try to crop it in picturebox in strechmode it takes the coordinates of original size of the image(1200,750) but i need to crop with the coordinates of the image displayed in picturebox(450,300), therefore i am getting faulty results in cropping. I am working with visual studio 2013 in c# winforms. Please provide me with a solution. Thank you in advance.

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Starting point of the selection:
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            _selecting = true;
            _selection = new Rectangle(new Point(e.X, e.Y), new Size());
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Update the actual size of the selection:
        if (_selecting)
        {
            _selection.Width = e.X - _selection.X;
            _selection.Height = e.Y - _selection.Y;

            // Redraw the picturebox:
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Make a note that we "have the mouse". 
        bHaveMouse = true;

        // Store the "starting point" for this rubber-band rectangle. 
        ptOriginal.X = e.X;
        ptOriginal.Y = e.Y;

        // Special value lets us know that no previous 
        // rectangle needs to be erased. 

        // Display coordinates 
        //lbCordinates.Text = "Coordinates  :  " + e.X.ToString() + ", " + e.Y.ToString();

        //ptLast.X = -1;
        //ptLast.Y = -1;

        //rectCropArea = new Rectangle(new Point(e.X, e.Y), new Size()); 
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && _selecting)
        {
            // Create cropped image:
            Image img = pictureBox1.Image.Crop(_selection);

            // Fit image to the picturebox:
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            pictureBox1.Image = img.Fit2PictureBox(pictureBox1);
            _selecting = false;
        }
        button5.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_selecting)
        {
            // Draw a rectangle displaying the current selection
            Pen pen = Pens.GreenYellow;
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, _selection);
        }
    }
```

`                                                                              the namespace class i used is as follows

```
namespace gfoidl.Imaging
{

    public static class ImageExtension
    {

        public static Image Crop(this Image image, Rectangle selection)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = image as Bitmap;

            // Check if it is a bitmap:
            if (bmp == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Kein gültiges Bild (Bitmap)");

            // Crop the image:
            Bitmap cropBmp = bmp.Clone(selection, bmp.PixelFormat);

            // Release the resources:
            image.Dispose();

            return cropBmp;
        }

        public static Image Fit2PictureBox( this Image image, PictureBox picBox)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = null;
            Graphics g;

            // Scale:
            double scaleY = (double)image.Width / picBox.Width;
            double scaleX = (double)image.Height / picBox.Height;
            double scale = scaleY < scaleX ? scaleX : scaleY;

            // Create new bitmap:
            bmp = new Bitmap(
                (int)((double)image.Width / scale),
                (int)((double)image.Height / scale));

            // Set resolution of the new image:
            bmp.SetResolution(
                image.HorizontalResolution,
                image.VerticalResolution);

            // Create graphics:
            g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

            // Set interpolation mode:
            //g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

            // Draw the new image:

            g.DrawImage(
                image,
                new Rectangle(          // Ziel
                    0, 0,
                    bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                new Rectangle(          // Quelle
                    0, 0,
                    image.Width, image.Height),
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            picBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

            // Release the resources of the graphics:
            g.Dispose();

            // Release the resources of the origin image:
            image.Dispose();

            return bmp;
        }
    }
}   //invoked it in the main program with the header using gfoid1.imaging;
```

Comment: Lets see if i understand. You select a part of an image in picbox and you want that part to be the new image in picbox. Am i right?

Comment: You dont need to set the size mode of picbox again and again. Do it once when the form loads or in the designer.

Comment: In *Fit2PictureBox* you first scale the image to picbox size corectly and then you are stretching the image! Why? Either scale or stretch. Not both

Comment: thank you so much it worked well @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε . when my make selection tool exceeds the picturebox it throws an error stating system.outofmemoryexception and it is also not letting me drag the makeselection tool from anyother direction than top left corner to bottom right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private Point mouseDown;

private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        _selecting = true;

        mouseDown = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        _selection = new Rectangle(mouseDown, new Size());
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (_selecting)
    {
        Point mousePos = new Point(e.X, e.Y);

        if(mousePos.X < 0)
        {
            mousePos.X = 0;
        }

        if(mousePos.X >= pictureBox1.Width)
        {
            mousePos.X = pictureBox1.Width - 1;
        }

        if(mousePos.Y < 0)
        {
            mousePos.Y = 0;
        }

        if (mousePos.Y >= pictureBox1.Height)
        {
            mousePos.Y = pictureBox1.Height - 1;
        }


        _selection.X = Math.Min(mouseDown.X, mousePos.X);
        _selection.Y = Math.Min(mouseDown.Y, mousePos.Y);
        _selection.Width = Math.Abs(mousePos.X - mouseDown.X);
        _selection.Height = Math.Abs(mousePos.Y - mouseDown.Y);

        // Redraw the picturebox:
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and the other answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a proper selection in all directions without leaving picbox:

```
private Point mouseDown;

private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            _selecting = true;

            mouseDown = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            _selection = new Rectangle(mouseDown, new Size());
        }
    }

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_selecting)
        {
            Point mousePos = new Point(e.X, e.Y);

            if(mousePos.X < 0)
            {
                mousePos.X = 0;
            }

            if(mousePos.X >= pictureBox1.Width)
            {
                mousePos.X = pictureBox1.Width - 1;
            }

            if(mousePos.Y < 0)
            {
                mousePos.Y = 0;
            }

            if (mousePos.Y >= pictureBox1.Height)
            {
                mousePos.Y = pictureBox1.Height - 1;
            }


            _selection.X = Math.Min(mouseDown.X, mousePos.X);
            _selection.Y = Math.Min(mouseDown.Y, mousePos.Y);
            _selection.Width = Math.Abs(mousePos.X - mouseDown.X);
            _selection.Height = Math.Abs(mousePos.Y - mouseDown.Y);

            // Redraw the picturebox:
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
    }
```